# How is this array joining a string?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Question about delimiter :

```
console.log(Array(2).join('a'));
console.log(['', '', ''].join('a'));
```

Why does the above code only return:

```
a
aa
```

instead of:

```
aa
aaa
```

Array(2) creates an array with two empty or undefined elements in an array [undefined, undefined], so shouldn’t it output `aa`?

Comment: `['', '', ''].join('a')` gives something like `''a''a''` which is nothing but `aa`

Comment: Try `console.log(['b', 'b', 'b'].join('a'));`, then you'll understand how that array are joined.

Comment: Ah that makes total sense, thanks!

Comment: `join` puts a sepearator in between two elements of an array. If you have 2 elements in the array, there is only one "between". If you have three elements there are two "betweens"

Answer (score 1):

Because when you are calling `.join('a')`, you are basically placing `a`s **in between** the objects and concatenating them.

Here, `['', '', ''].join('a')` will produce `aa`, because there are only two **in-between** places where `a` can be placed and concatenated.

Same reasoning for `Array(2).join('a')`